# $A$ is a square matrix. Prove that if $v$ is a vector in Row $A$ and Null $A$, then $v=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors, orthogonality

> Let $A$ be a square matrix.  Prove that if $v$ is a vector in the rowspace of $A$ and also in the the nullspace of $A$, then $v=0$.

The textbook mentions that $v\cdot v = 0$, but I'm having trouble understanding where they got that from.

Comment: Are there some other conditions on $A$?

Comment: No, that's all that's stated. I don't seem to understand the connection between Row A and Null A interns of orthogonality.

Comment: Nevermind, I was thinking in terms of Col A and Null A.

Comment: You put the problem statement almost entirely in the title, but this material needs to be fully presented in the body of the Question.  In its current form Readers may find the title cryptic as a problem statement, and it makes things easier to connect if the greater space allowed by the body text is used to give the setup and specify what you want to ask about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{r}{\text{Row}}$
$\newcommand{\null}{\text{Null}}$
Well, this is one of the most fundamental theorems in Linear Algebra:

> The rowspace and the nullspace of a matrix $A$ are orthogonal subspaces.

**Proof:**
Let $x\in \r(A)$ and $ y \in \null(A).$ We are going to prove that $x,y$ are orthogonal, i.e. $x^Ty = 0.$

Since $x \in \r(A)\implies \exists z: x = A^Tz$ (this means that $x$ is written as a linear combination of the rows of $A$). Also, since $y\in \null(A) \implies Ay = 0.$ Thus, we have:

$$x^T y = (A^Tz)^Ty = z^TAy = z^T \cdot 0 = 0.$$

In our specific case, we know that $v\in \r(A) $ and $v \in \null(A).$ Hence:
$$v^Tv = 0 \implies \|v\|^2 = 0\implies v = 0.$$